# SQL divide count from two table with where clause

Tags: sql

I am trying to count record in [Supplier table] where supplierid=2
and divide by count record in [detail table] where address=az

the common field for both table is carid=cardid

thank you so much!

Comment: What's the part with which you are having difficulty?

Comment: Hello love welcome to StackOverflow, next time try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
And for sql questions please include your rdbms and data sample with input and desire output. Also read
[**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you.  The count of the details is selected into a sub query table so then you can use the results to divide into your main table count.

```
SELECT  s.carid, COUNT(*), detail_table.DetailCount, COUNT(*) / detail_table.DetailCount
     FROM supplier s,
    (SELECT  d.carid,  COUNT(*) DetailCount
        FROM details d
        WHERE d.address=az
        GROUP BY d.carid) detail_table
     WHERE  s.supplierid=2 and s.carid=detail_table.carid
     GROUP BY s.carid, detail_table.DetailCount
```

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing a litle bit to do this.

You need join both tables, apply filters in `where` and then count.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM 
   [Supplier table]  s INNER JOIN 
   [detail table] d on s.carid= d.carid
WHERE s.supplierid=2 
and d.address=az
```

This may be a litle more generic. This group all the `s.supplierid` and count each group

```
SELECT s.supplierid, count(*)
FROM 
   [Supplier table]  s INNER JOIN 
   [detail table] d on s.carid= d.carid
WHERE d.address=az
GROUP BY s.supplierid
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but where is the "/" (divide) in your query?

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. That is why you should include some sample data and desire output. Just reading your question I don't understand what values you want divide. I could try guessing but you could help adding more info to your question.